# CountDownTimer not stopped after moving to next activity - Quiz application

Tags: android, android-layout

sorry for my English,

I have quiz application consist of `RecyclerView`, so when I click to item in that RecyclerView, it should move to questions part which is 5 questions in 5 activities. so I made `CountDownTimer` for 15 seconds for each question in each activity, when the user answer question than click button, it moves to another activity but the CountDownTimer still running in background, whenever I go back to my RecyclerView, another activity appear with 15 seconds so I don't know why those CountDownTimers do not stop. need help

**second_five_questions_questions_1.java**

```
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private RadioButton radioButton;
private Button btnDisplay;
private TextView mTextField;
private CountDownTimer myCount;
public long val;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_five_questions_q1);

}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Rd_Group_Second_five_Questions_q1);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_SECOND_btn_Five_Questions_q1);
    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId =radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            myCount.cancel();
            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            if(selectedId==R.id.Rd_btn_three__second_five_questions_q1)
            {
                val++;
                Intent intent = new Intent( second_five_questions_questions_1.this, second_five_questions_questions_2.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", val);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            else
            {
                val = 0;
                //When user Choose Wrong choice
                Intent intent = new Intent( second_five_questions_questions_1.this, second_five_questions_questions_2.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", val);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }

    });

    myCount=new CountDownTimer(16000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                                        //Error might be here
            mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimerClock_first_Five_Questions_Q1);
            mTextField.setText("Time left:"+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            if(millisUntilFinished / 1000 == 5)
            {
                mTextField.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }


        public void onFinish() {
            val = 0;                                                                            // When time finish go for mainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent( second_five_questions_questions_1.this, second_five_questions_questions_2.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", val);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
}}
```

**CustomRecyclerAdapter.java**

```
private Context context;
private List<TestsUtils> TestsUTils;


public CustomRecyclerAdapterTests(Context context, List testutils) {

    this.context = context;
    this.TestsUTils = testutils;
}


@Override
public CustomRecyclerAdapterTests.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_list_item_tests, parent, false);
    CustomRecyclerAdapterTests.ViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomRecyclerAdapterTests.ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomRecyclerAdapterTests.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.itemView.setTag(TestsUTils.get(position));
    TestsUtils pu = TestsUTils.get(position);
    holder.Subject_Title.setText(pu.GetTestName());
    holder.Subject_Description.setText(pu.GetTestSubject());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return TestsUTils.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView Subject_Title;
    public TextView Subject_Description;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        Subject_Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Title_Single_List_Item_Tests);
        Subject_Description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Subject_Single_List_Item_Tests);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                switch (getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        TestsUtils obj1 = (TestsUtils) view.getTag();
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Test-One", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intentone = new Intent(context, com.example.computer.policeproject.Questions_package.First_Five_Questions.first_five_Questions_questions_1.class);
                        context.startActivity(intentone);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        TestsUtils obj2 = (TestsUtils) view.getTag();
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Test-One", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intenttwo = new Intent(context, com.example.computer.policeproject.Questions_package.First_Five_Questions.first_five_Questions_questions_1.class);
                        context.startActivity(intenttwo);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: share your complete activity and recyclerview adapter class code.

Comment: its very big of code maybe can't pest it, am gona try!

Comment: @Sahil i edited my post

Comment: am really facing this problem for 6 days now help plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling countdown by adding:

```
myCount.cancel();
```

before you finish the activity.

in your code:

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    val = 0;                                                                            // When time finish go for mainActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent( second_five_questions_questions_1.this, second_five_questions_questions_2.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", val);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    cancel(); // add this to cancel out countdown
    finish();
}
```

Comment: where should i add this code brother am newbie in android studio

Comment: it helped me. Thank you.

Comment: u saved my job.

Comment: for example when i reach question number 4 and click back , after few seconds countdowntimer opening the last activity

Comment: it appears same problem too , when i open first question and than press back to recycler view , countdown timer open the first question and to on ... i think i did not solved my issue

Comment: either you are missing the cancel() command of timer or creating new instance of timer. Try debugging your code.

Comment: can i send the project for you brother , am gona  lose my job coz of this error plz.

Comment: sure send it at contact.sahil27@gmail.com

Comment: I have send the project.